# Angular JS ng-click content not showing on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have products displayed using this code:

```
<a ng-click="setSelection(product);" class="btn btn-sm">Full details</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zhsY6TAjONewyInGiwUC?p=preview

Everything works fine locally on various browsers, but now I have uploaded the content to the website, nothing is displaying when I click on 'full details'.

http://gammafightwear.co.uk/gamma-website/products-long-sleeved.html

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be?

Many thanks

Comment: As Josh stated, it looks like you're referencing to wrong files (paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a 404 when I click on that button.

> GET http://gammafightwear.co.uk/gamma-website/includes/products/ESSCOT.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Same here. Different product (long sleeved rash guards) GET http://gammafightwear.co.uk/gamma-website/includes/products/ESORG.html 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Oh dear, I just realized my json file has the codes in uppercase, thanks for your help in discovering my stupid mistake!! Thanks :-)